# jQuery scripts don't want to work together

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website. I am doing responsive menu and jQuery script work but not good. I mean that every single script wokrs very well but all of them together don't want to work that good. The first one, this from responsive menu is killing every thing, so this menu is not working as it should be :/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.sticky.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".menu-trigger").click(function(){
            $("#mainnav").slideToggle(900);
        });
    });

    jQuery(function($)
    {
        //zresetuj scrolla
        $.scrollTo(0);

        $('#link').click(function() { $.scrollTo($('#zjazd'), 2000); });
    }
    );

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#container").sticky({topSpacing:0});

    });

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
                $('.scrollup').fadeIn('slow');
            } else {
                $('.scrollup').fadeOut('fast');
            }
        });

        //Kliknij aby przewinąć do góry
        $('.scrollup').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1500);
            return false;
        });

    });

</script>
```

So what is wrong? What is going om? I'm still learning and it can be really silly problem but for today for me...

All website is responsive already.

[You can see here what's wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcby2.jpg)

When I delete rest of scripts and leave only this for responsive menu it works beautiful, when I delete this for responsive menu then all rest works well, but when all scripts are together then only this for menu works not well but rest of it works normal. I don't know what is going on.

I'm still learning... and the website which I'm working od is pretty good.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add the code directly into the question, instead of posting a screenshot. You can add the code by indenting it with four spaces.

Comment: Perhaps the order of your included scripts should be different? I would think that jQuery would need to load before any extensions but could be wrong

Comment: Hi @Zack. No, I don't get any errors in my browser.

Comment: @Antonio Menete, I don't think I understand. What do you mean by load jQuery first?

Comment: @Karol Must've been a typo. When I commented `jquery.scrollTo.min.js` and `jquery.sticky.js` were loaded before `jquery-2.2.3.min.js`

Answer (score 1):

You only need one `$(document).ready(function() { });`

And the first thing inside of it should be calling the plugins you want to use.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").sticky({topSpacing:0});

    $.scrollTo(0);

    $(".menu-trigger").click(function(){
        $("#mainnav").slideToggle(900);
    });


    $('#link').click(function() { 
        $.scrollTo($('#zjazd'), 2000); 
    });

    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1500);
        return false;
    });
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $('.scrollup').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Adosi, thanks for your help, but I don't use any plugin becouse it's just standard element of jQuery library so it still works the same. And I don't udnerstand at all one thing you wrote about calling the plugins, becouse I called the plugins before but this menu one don't need plugin.

Comment: `jquery.sticky.js` is a plugin.

Comment: Yes I know but I don't understand what has that got to do with my problem :/ Can you fully explain what do you mean?